# Add class after scroll to section, when feel and animation to id

Tags: javascript, jquery, alignment

I search scripts, which will be behaviour during scroll: http://www.dishoom.com/.

I have three sections of the site and would like to scrollowaniu to the middle of the section equalized it to the upper position. The example is above

Regards

Comment: can you post the code you have so far and the details of the issue you are having?

Comment: Your question is too vague, you might want to add what you've tried and a better description of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have three sections home_bg,barman,galeria. I want, that after scroll to section who feel $(window).scrollTop() add class. When this scroll <= 0.5 * height feeling section, auto scroll to top feeling section

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                   scroll = $(window).scrollTop();


                var height_check = jQuery(window).height() ;
                $(document).mousewheel(function (event) {
                    if (event.deltaY) {
                        $(window).scroll(function () {

                            if(scroll >= $("section#home_bg").offset().top)
                            {
                                $('section#barman').removeClass('snaps-active');
                                $('section#galeria').removeClass('snaps-active');
                                $('section#home_bg').addClass('snaps-active');

                                if(scroll >= ($("section#home_bg").offset().top + (0.5*height_check)))
                                {
                                    $('section#home_bg').removeClass('snaps-active');

                                }
                            }
                            if (scroll >= $("section#barman").offset().top) {
                                $('section#barman').addClass('snaps-active');
                                $('section#galeria').removeClass('snaps-active');
                                $('section#home_bg').removeClass('snaps-active');

                                if(scroll >= ($("section#barman").offset().top + (0.5*height_check)))
                                {
                                    $('section#barman').removeClass('snaps-active');

                                }

                            }
                            if(scroll >= ($("section#galeria").offset().top)) {
                                $('section#home_bg').removeClass('snaps-active');
                                $('section#barman').removeClass('snaps-active');
                                $('section#galeria').addClass('snaps-active');


                                if (scroll >= ($("section#galeria").offset().top + (0.5 * height_check))) {
                                    $('section#galeria').removeClass('snaps-active');
                                }


                            }


                        });






                    }









                });





            });



        });
    </script>
```